# Prove that if $c\mid a-b$ and $c\mid a+b$ then $c \mid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a, b, c$ be integers.

$c\mid a-b$ implies $a-b = cm$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

$c \mid a+b$ implies $a+b = cn$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$(a-b)+(a+b) = cm + cn = c (m+n)$

$2a = c(m+n)$

Then I have no idea.

Comment: consider the case $a=3$, $b=1$, $c=2$.

Comment: It isn't true.  $2\,|\,3-1$ and $2\,|\,3+1$ but  $2\,\nmid 3$.

Comment: Note that $c$ has to be odd for this to hold. Else, all you know is that $c$ divides $(a-b)+(a+b) = 2a$.

Answer (score 1):

In point of fact, this is false: $2\mid 3-1$, $2\mid 3+1$ and $2\nmid 3$.